# Combine intersecting polygons in QGIS

Tags: object, polygon, qgis

I've created a new file of intersecting polygons (20 metre buffer of points).  I would like to combine the polygons using QGIS, but not to combine them into one layer, with one single attribute table entry if you see what I mean - in order to reduce the number of single polygons in the layer.  I've created an attribute field in the table for each polygon as ROWID.  I would then like to output the centroid co-ordinates of each combined polygon (eastings & northings) using QGIS.